# How can I differ between different chrome profiles in my rules?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-11, google-chrome-extensions, userscripts

What could be the difference between [multiple profiles](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform=Desktop) on Google Chrome? I want to make specific rules for specific chrome profiles:
What is the difference between different profiles on Google Chrome out of these options?

1. Windows Tile.
2. Process Name.
3. Process Path.
4. Window Class.

The different profile shortcuts open the same executable called: chrome.exe.
The shortcuts only differ in shortcut arguments.

Picture for Google Chrome profiles demonstration:
[image: Google Chrome Profiles]
[image: Google Chrome Profiles 2]

Comment: Can you please explain which "rules" you are talking about, where are you setting them? The difference in profile is quite clear in the Google article you linked, all settings and changes (besides raw browser code) are separate, that includes all extensions, browsing data, settings, etc.

Comment: I found the difference between is command line argument and that's it it is the same program but with different argument at start.

Comment: Not sure how this is the answer to your question since this information you already posted as part of the question...

Comment: I never know I can check for command line arguments in programs.

Answer (score 0):

I found the difference between them is command line argument. it is the same program for all the profiles but with different argument at start.